# A triangular "spot function"

Tags: trigonometry, 3d, surfaces

**z = (cos πx + cos πy)** represents the classical "[spot function](http://www.fho-emden.de/~hoffmann/spot290800.pdf)", made by square cells, used in every laser printer's halftone screening. Does anyone knows the corresponding function to produce TRIANGULAR cells instead of squared ones?

Comment: $\sum_{i=1}^3 \sin(x\cos\theta_i+y\sin\theta_i)$, where $\theta_i = 2\pi i/3$. http://i.stack.imgur.com/OqaQz.png

Comment: This is very interesting, but not usable in my case... Many thanks, however!

Comment: That's funny, because after application of some trigonometric identities Hagen's and mine are exactly the same apart from a $90^\circ$ rotation and a scaling.

Comment: You are right! Unfortunately I am not so skilled to appreciate all that at a glance. You answer is very good! Now I see it. Excuse me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is, you want a function such that the contour $z=0$ is a triangle (or triangular lattice)?
I suggest
$$ z(x,y)=\sin\left(\tfrac{2 y}{\sqrt 3}\right)\cdot \sin\left(x+\tfrac y{\sqrt 3}\right)\cdot \sin\left(x-\tfrac y{\sqrt 3}\right)$$

Comment: Many thanks, Hagen; this is the solution I were looking for...